# C++14 Initializing inherited member in class constructor initialization list

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

I have a base class

```
class A
{
    protected:

    int a;
};
```

And a class which is derived:

```
class B : public A
{

    B(int a_val)
        : a{a_val} // not allowed by compiler?
    {
    }
};
```

I can solve the problem by:

```
    B(int a_val)
    {
        a = a_val;
    }
```

Is this "the solution", or can I do what I originally tried to do?

Of course, I could do this:

```
    B(int a_val)
        : A(a_val)
    {
    }
```

and change `class A`

```
    A(int a_val)
        : a{a_val}
    {
    }
```

However this isn't really "better" in the context of what I am doing.

In reply to an answer below (by swang): Can I therefore do this?

```
B(int a_val)
    : A(), a{a_val}
{
}
```

Comment: @LogicStuff I can't see how that's a duplicate myself

Comment: @Mikhail linked question is very similar, but different problem I believe

Answer (score 3):

When you do this:

```
class B : public A
{

    B(int a_val)
        : a{a_val} // not allowed by compiler?
    {
    }
};
```

You are trying to initialise a variable that doesn't belong to class B yet, so the right solution is

```
B(int a_val)
   : A(a_val)
{
};
```

You can do this

```
B(int a_val)
{
    a = a_val;
};
```

Because before a = a_val, the default construct of A has been called, and A::a has been default initialised.

Comment: Thanks, see my question to you in my question above (which I have appended)

Comment: no you can't , because a has been initialised by A(), you are then trying to initialise it again, by doing a = a_val, you are using the assignment operator, not the copy constructor.